# reversing input - undefined output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
  char zahl[255];
  cin>>zahl;
  for(int i=255; i>=0; i--)
    if(zahl[i] != 0)
      cout<<zahl[i];

  cout<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When I enter some words the input gets reversed but before and after that there are undefined expressions. Can someone explain the reason for this?
As far as I understood, the char array is filled with the inserted expression (from [0] on), the rest is filled with '\0's. By the if condition I skip the '\0's. Where do the undefined expressions come from?

ty
greets CS

Comment: Try using [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/?kw=reverse) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Your problem is generally that `zahl` will have the sentinel character `'\0'` somewhere at an index before 254. Leave that alone, and only reverse characters before it.

Comment: Example using `std::string` and `std::reverse`: http://ideone.com/HL1znW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initially, the array is uninitialised and contains garbage. `cin` writes the input followed by a single zero to terminate; the rest of the array still contains garbage, which your loop outputs before the input.

You could specify that the array be zero-initialised:

```
char zahl[255] = {};
```

Or you could measure the string length, and start from there:

```
for (int i=std::strlen(zahl)-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Or, better still, use the standard library to fix the potential buffer overrun:

```
std::string zahl;
std::cin >> zahl;
std::copy(zahl.rbegin(), zahl.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

Comment: You should also be able to use `char zahl[255]{0};` to zero initialize the array.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, there are a variety of ways to zero-initialise it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for loop` will run 256 times, assuming that the word entered is 255 characters long. However, user input will vary in length, so instead calculate the length and use it in the `for loop`.

`int len = strlen(zahl);`

The code will now be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main(){
char zahl[255];
cin>>zahl;
int len = strlen(zahl);
for(int i=len-1; i>=0; i--)
  if(zahl[i] != 0)
    cout<<zahl[i];

 cout<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```